# How to create ONE Post route to allow changes/updates on many pages as admin?

Tags: laravel

I have created an app and now it should allow an admin to update the content from the fronted. I have integrated TinyMCE. So far so good. However, instead of creating 100's of routes

```
Route::post('/category1/person1', [
    'uses' => 'MainController@infoupdate',
    'as' => 'infoupdate',
]);

Route::post('/category1/person2', [
    'uses' => 'MainController@infoupdate',
    'as' => 'infoupdate2',
]);
```

etc...

With DRY principle in mind, I want to use only ONE route. 
I have tried using the **where** filter but that is giving me an error:

> missing route parameters

```
Route::post('/{type}/{person}', [
    'uses' => 'MainController@infoupdate',
    'as' => 'infoupdate',
])->where(['type' => '(actors|authors)', 'person' => '.*']);
```

The View:

```
@if($admin)
    <form action="{{ route('infoupdate') }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textareaeditor"></label>
            <textarea name="content" rows="10" class="form-control" id="textareaeditor"></textarea>
        </div>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
@endif
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Missing required parameters for [Route: infoupdate] [URI: {type}/Chelsea_Handler]. (View: /home/vagrant/code/testsite/resources/views/page.blade.php)

Comment: So that’s when you’re creating a link? What’s the code you’re using in your view?

Comment: @Updated the question with the View Code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your view. When creating the form, you must pass the required parameters for creating the route:

```
@if($admin)
<form action="{{ route('infoupdate', ['type' => 'actors', 'person' => 'person1']) }}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textareaeditor"></label>
        <textarea name="content" rows="10" class="form-control" id="textareaeditor"></textarea>
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
@endif
```